# A negative idea following "unless"

Tags: conjunctions, negation, multiple-negation

Is it acceptable to use a negation after "unless"? I know it's far from standard.

> You don't love people. But you will succeed **unless you don't** like people.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any reason not to use a negative after *unless*. I can give examples unless you'd rather not hear them. :) "We could go out for pizza, unless you don't want pizza?" "You might try using cilantro, unless you don't have any. Then you might try parsley." As a matter of fact, I don't see anything wrong with the example in the OP.

Comment: unless you don't love people. was supposed to mean "unless you hate people. "

Comment: @user1425  Ah, that makes more sense. You know you can edit it, right? You can also say "You don't love people. You will succeed unless you don't like people."

Comment: But I did it on purpose to illustrate a case in point .

Comment: To repeat yourself using *unless* is more problematic than using the negative. Was that a part of your question?

Comment: I think the repetition is a by-product here. The main point was a possibility of using a negation after UNLESS.

Comment: @user1425  So, what problem do you see with, "You don't love people. You will succeed unless you don't like people"?

Comment: It's not that I saw a problem I just needed to make sure that there was no problem.

Comment: It's just that the line you use says, "You don't X. You will succeed unless you don't X" Do you mean to say that you won't succeed unless you *do* X? Or that you will succeed if you *do* X?

Comment: I wanted to say "unless you do not do X?"

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but why not leave "love" in the first part, and change it to "like" in the second part? Then there is no weirdness about repeating after the *unless*?

Comment: I am not against that. It's just that I was more concerned with a grammatical aspect rather than a lexical one.

Comment: Then I recommend that you make the change because grammatically there is no difference, but leaving it as it is begs a question that you you don't mean to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it won't be a preferred version. It's not that natural as compared to...

> You'll not succeed unless you love people

Note: I've not factually examined this sentence!

Most grammar books says avoiding two negatives to make things positive.

> Prefer *It's common* over *It's not uncommon.*

Comment: As the negation of "you will succeed", "you won't" sounds more natural to me than "you'll not". But that could be just me.

Comment: Just because it's not uncommon doesn't mean it's common.

Comment: The phrase ["not uncommon" isn't double negation.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/are-not-uncommon-and-similar-phrases-double-negatives-should-their-use-be-avo)

Comment: @helix really? then what's it?

Comment: @starsplusplus If something is not uncommon, it's **not** common as well. How? Please enlighten me.

Comment: @MaulikV See the [link in my previous comment.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/are-not-uncommon-and-similar-phrases-double-negatives-should-their-use-be-avo) It's a [figure of speech known as litotes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes)

Comment: Related question to @starsplusplus's comment: [ELU: Does “not uncommon” mean “common”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6124/does-not-uncommon-mean-common)

Comment: @helix you are taking rarest rare things and considering exceptions. Take 10 sentences with *not uncommon* from anywhere and 8 out of 10 would mean *not uncommon* as *common*. And, this example is taken from Swan's book whereas the answerer in your link I think had to thought about that example to prove the point.

Comment: @Maulik The point is that "not uncommon" also includes the middle ground that is neither common nor uncommon. "Common" is a *subset* of "not uncommon" that does **not** include this middle ground.

Answer (score 1):

I think

> Unless you play badly, you will win the game

Is the same as

> If you play well, you will win the game.

Comment: Hi sadar, welcome to this community!

Comment: @sardar Welcome to the community, and thanks for the tip! However, I think you probably misread the question a little. It's true that the title asks about "a negative idea", but in the body of the question, the original poster expands on that a little that it actually is about "a negation after 'unless'".

Answer (score 0):

**Unless** - except under the circumstances that

**Ex:** Exceptional talent does not always win its reward unless favored by exceptional circumstances.

From *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*

**Unless** implies a negative impression. It means "if not the case that..."

If the clause after "**unless**" is negative, the negative of the clause and the implied negative of "**unless**" makes the total positive. It's the case of two negatives makes positive in a sentence. And in standard English we generally avoid these kind of construction. Though they are not uncommon, especially in some circumstances it does make more sense.